# My site has been crash when i add some php code

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

My site has been crash when i add these php code in index.php in template folder:

```
<?php
                    if (!class_exists( 'VmModel' )) require_once(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'components'.DS.'com_virtuemart'.DS.'helpers'.DS.'vmmodel.php');
                    if (!class_exists( 'VmConfig' )) require_once(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_virtuemart'.DS.'helpers'.DS.'config.php');
                    if(!class_exists('VirtueMartCart')) require_once(JPATH_VM_SITE.DS.'helpers'.DS.'cart.php');
                    $hv_cart = VirtueMartCart::getCart(true);
                    foreach( $hv_cart->products as $pkey =>$prow ){?>
                        <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr" style="width: 48px;">
                            <?php echo $prow->image-> displayMediaThumb('style="height: 36px; width: 100%"',false); ?>
                            <span>SL:<?php echo $prow->quantity; ?></span>
                            <span class="hv_hidden" product_id="<?php echo $prow->virtuemart_product_id; ?>" quantity="<?php echo $prow->quantity; ?>"> </span>
                        </li>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
```

when i visit homepage the server show error:

> Fatal error: main() [function.main]: The
>   script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete
>   object. Please ensure that the class definition "VmImage" of
>   the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before*
>   unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load
>   the class definition in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\chovietnam.com\templates\it_thestore4\index.php on
>   line 68

line 68 make error is

```
<?php echo $prow->image-> displayMediaThumb('style="height: 36px; width: 100%"',false); ?>
```

the first time i visit homepage it still work well, but when i visit home page again, it make error. And i clear all cookie, cache... of browser it will ok again and make error when i visit homepage again. but if i visit other page (not homepage, and those code still work in that page) there is no error appear
anyone can help me solve this problem, i use Joomla 2.5 and Virtuemart 2. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that somewhere within the PHP code (not necessarily code you've written), `unserialize` is getting called. The data represents a class that does not exist at the time of the call to `unserialize`. As such, PHP can't really unserialize it: it cannot create an instance of a class that does not exist. Add a `class_exists` check and `require_once` statement for `VmImage` as well.

Comment: the first time i visit homepage it still work well, but when i visit home page again, it make error. And i clear all cookie, cache... of browser it will ok again and make error when i visit homepage again. error appear only homepage, not in other page (althought my code work in this page too)

Comment: i already have class_exists check in above code

Comment: @user1912285: I know you already have some. Add *another*, but for `VmImage`.

Comment: thanks but i need image to show products, do u know another way to get image, id, quantity from cart?

Comment: or get image from product id?

Comment: @user1912285: I am saying that what you are doing *should work* if only you make sure that `VmImage` is `require`d into your PHP script. You have already done that for `VmModel` and `VmConfig`; now do it for `VmImage`.

Comment: im already include VmMediaHandler but cant fix this error

Comment: finally i fixed that error, just move that code to another module and it work, lol, i dont understand that.thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like:
When you visit your site including your code above, VM is storing some thing in the session/cockie. 
When you vist again it will fail because the session is restored, but your php classes loaded by your code are not loaded at that time.

Try to load your VM-classes as early as possible or better at  the VM classes to the autoload function

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<? php echo $prow->image-> displayMediaThumb('style=\"height: 36px; width: 100%\"',false); ?>
```

Comment: do u mean i repalce "<?php" with "<? php" ?

Comment: Double quotes need not be escaped within single quotes.

Comment: try to put back slash before doublequotes

Comment: i try this but the error still appear